# Physics behind hissing sound when opening something that is vacuum sealed?

Tags: pressure, acoustics, vacuum, vibrations

I am aware that it is the differences in pressure, and gases rushing into the container that makes the sound occur.

But, what exactly is responsible for making the audible *hiss* sound when this happens? What are the physics behind this?

Comment: In brief, it's caused by the turbulent flow as air enters the container. [Aeroacoustics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeroacoustics) is the branch of physics that describes these sound generation processes in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, the pressure difference between the outside volume and the vacuum sealed volume creates a gas flow into the vacuum sealed volume when the two volumes are joined together (i.e. there is no resistance to the flow or, lets say, air.

The rapid movement of air at the boundaries of the two volumes results in a turbulent airflow, which results in a sound that resembles white noise (because of the chaotic nature of the event at a small scale). To reduce a complex matter: sound is created by pressure differences and sound waves reflect at boundaries. Here we have both, sound pressure differences and boundaries.

You create a similar airflow when you vocalize "s", for example. By creating a tight passage between your vocal tract and the outside air, you create a turbulent airflow that results in a "white noise"-like sound.

Here is further reading on turbulence:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbulence

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly the answer I was looking for.